# Is the Node/Noodle Code Written in C or Python?

Tags: python, node-editor

I've been trying to figure out if the node/noodle code in Blender is written in C or Python. Anyone know?

And if so (if I may be allowed a follow-up) can you point it out for me (file, if not starting line)?

Comment: You can create new nodes in Python if that is what you are referring to...there are many projects that do this, e.g., Sverchok and Modular Tree.

Comment: It's all C, the compositor isn't well exposed to the API yet. Although you can create a pynode tree, it's a lot of work since a whole ecosystem is necessary to cache your results etc. In addition to that it is probably really slow. If you'd like to create a custom c node, see: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Nazg-gul/WritingNewNode